# Fast way to store different length Matrix rows into Cell

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, vectorization, cell-array

I have three matrices:

```
Values = [200x7] doubles
numOfStrings = [82    78    75    73    72    71    70] %(for example)
numOfColumns = [1 4]
```

The `numOfColumns` may contain any set of distinct values from 1 to 7. For example `[1 2 3]` or `[4 7]` or `[1 5 6 7]`. Obviously, biggest `numOfColumns` that can be is `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]`.

`numOfColumns` show the columns I want to get. `numOfStrings` shows the rows of that columns I need. I.e. in my example I want to get columns `1` and `4`. So from the `1` column I want to get the `82` first rows and from the `4th` get the `73` first rows.

i.e. if `numOfColumns = [1 4]` then

```
myCell{1} = Values( 1:82,1); % Values(numOfStrings(numOfColumn(1)), numOfColumn(1))
myCell{2} = Values( 1:73,4); % Values(numOfStrings(numOfColumn(2)), numOfColumn(2))
```

P.S. That's not necessary to save it into cell array. If you can offer any another solution Ill be grateful to you.

---

I'm looking for the fastest way to do this, which is likely to be by avoiding `for` loops and using vectorization.

I think a lot about `sub2ind` function. But I can't figure out how to return arrays of the different size! Because `myCell{1} - [82x1]` and `myCell{2} - [73x1]`. I suppose I can't use `bsxfun` or `arrayfun`.

---

**RESULTS:**

1. Using `for` loops alike [@Will 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41097992/4960953):

   ```
   for jj = 1:numel(numOfColumns)
       myCell{rowNumber(numOfColumns(jj)),numOfColumns(jj)} = Values( 1:numOfStrings(numOfColumns(jj)),numOfColumns(jj));
   end
   ```

   Elapsed time is 157 seconds
2. Using `arrayfun` alike [@Yishai E 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41099188/4960953):

   ```
   myCell(sub2ind(size(myCell),rowNumber(numOfColumns),numOfColumns)) = arrayfun( @(nOC) Values( 1:numOfStrings(nOC),nOC), numOfColumns, 'UniformOutput', false);
   ```

   Elapsed time is 179 seconds
3. Using `bsxfun` alike [@rahnema1 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41100759/4960953):

   ```
   idx = bsxfun(@ge,numOfStrings , (1:200).');
   extracted_values = Values (idx);
   tempCell = mat2cell(extracted_values,numOfStrings);
   myCell(sub2ind(size(myCell),rowNumber(numOfColumns),numOfColumns)) = myCell(numOfColumns)';
   ```

   Elapsed time is 204 seconds

SO, I got a lot of working answers, and some of them are vectorized as I asked, but `for` loops still fastest!

Comment: You can't avoid `for` loops with cell arrays.  However, recent versions of MATLAB have a much more improved JIT so loops are quite competitive compared to more standard vectorized approaches.

Comment: I think the benchmark is not correct

Comment: @rayryeng Two of three answers are not use `for`. But I think `for`-solution is faster because I can't implement vectorized code correctly...

Comment: @rahnema1Yep, I afraid, I can't implement your code efficiently - I used a lot of ancillary functions... But still can't figure out how to avoid them

Comment: I can no figure out how timing take 179 s . Can you provide a complete example with actual dimensions. what is `rowNumber`? just try this one: `numcols_logical = false(1,numel(numOfColumns)); numcols_logical(numOfColumns) = true; extracted_values = Values(bsxfun(@ge, numOfStrings .* numcols_logical , (1:200).')); result= mat2cell(extracted_values,numOfStrings(numcols_logical)); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
% Get number of elements in NUMOFCOLUMNS
n = numel(numOfColumns);

% Set up output
myCell = cell(1,n);    

% Loop through all NUMOFCOLUMNS values, storing to cell
for i = 1:n

    myCell{i} = Values(1:numOfStrings(numOfColumns(i)), numOfColumns(i));

end
```

Which for your example gives output

```
myCell = 

[82x1 double]    [73x1 double]
```

Comment: Yep, that works! Thank you! But do you know any solution in vectorized view? Just to avoid loop, like I asked in question?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Could you explain why you need a vectorized solution?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Agreed, but I have the above code running in under .05secs... Is it being called many times or for a much larger example than given above, in which case optimisation is key?

Comment: Exactly! I'll go for 5 million rows array and divide this for sets of unequal arrays like `myCell`. So calculation speed is very important in this case

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam For clarity, you repeatedly use the word "strings" in your question. Do you mean doubles? As its definition is not an actual line of MATLAB code, I'm unsure what `Values` is meant to be...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130396/discussion-between-mikhail-sam-and-will).

Comment: Will, looks like your answer is fastest one! Thank you! I added conclusions in my Question!

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam it might be that the other methods are glorified for loops with extra validity checks slowing things down! Please accept this answer if it is the best solution to your problem

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem, using arrayfun, which "vectorizes" the application of the indexing function. Not really, but it doesn't call the interpreter for each entry from numOfColumns. Interestingly enough, this is slower than the non-vectorized code in the other answer! (for 1e5 entries, 0.95 seconds vs. 0.23 seconds...)

```
arrayfun(@(nOC)Values(1:numOfStrings(nOC), nOC), numOfColumns, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Comment: Useful and fast enough code! Thank you! Maybe it can be fast as `for` loop if I avoid using `sub2ind` in my task.  I added conclusions in my Question!

Answer (score 1):

You can create logical indices for extraction of the desired elements :

```
idx = bsxfun(@ge,numOfStrings , (1:200).');
```

that in MATLAB R2016b or Octave (thanks to broadcasting/expansion) can be written as:

```
idx = numOfStrings >= (1:200).';
```

extract values:

```
extracted_values = Values (idx);
```

then using `mat2cell` convert data to cell :

```
myCell = mat2cell(extracted_values,numOfStrings);
```

all in one line :

```
myCell = mat2cell(Values (numOfStrings >= (1:200).'), numOfStrings);
```

If you want to use different `numOfColumns`  with different sizes to extract elements of the cell you can each time do this:

```
result = myCell(numOfColumns);
```

If both `numOfStrings` and `numOfColumns` change and you need to compute the result once do this:

```
%convert numOfColumns to logical index:
numcols_logical = false(1,7);
numcols_logical(numOfColumns) = true;
extracted_values = Values ((numOfStrings .* numcols_logical) >= (1:200).');
```

if you need cell array

```
result= mat2cell(extracted_values,numOfStrings(numcols_logical));
```

Comment: Works perfect! I didn't know  about this R2016b functionality, but I still use R2016a, so I used bsxfun. Maybe it works much faster in 2016b. Anyway Thank you! I added conclusions in my Question!